# Insert multiple values from select box to separate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 'Catch Reporting' form for our local fishing club and currently users can only submit one catch at a time so often have to go back to the form multiple times to report a day's catches.

I'm trying to adapt it so that the Species list becomes a multiple option select box instead.

Each catch needs to be its own row in the database.

This is the user-facing form which I have changed from a Select to Select Multiple:

```
<form action="addspecies.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="datecaught" id="todayDate"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getDate()
    {
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}
        today = yyyy+""+mm+""+dd;
        document.getElementById("todayDate").value = today;
    }
    //call getDate() when loading the page
    getDate();
    </script>
    <!--Date caught: <input type="date" name="datecaught"><p>-->
    <table width="600" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
    <td>Boat Name:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="boatname">
                <option value = "">---Select---</option>
                <?php
                $queryusers = "SELECT BoatName FROM SpeciesHuntBoats WHERE CatchYear2=$year ORDER BY BoatName ASC";
                $db = mysqli_query($db, $queryusers);
                while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
                    echo "<option value='".$d['BoatName']."'>".$d['BoatName']."</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Species:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="species" multiple size="5">
                <option value = "">---Select---</option><br>
                <?php
                $queryspecies = "Select Species from SpeciesHuntSpecies ORDER BY Species ASC";
                $db2 = mysqli_query($db2, $queryspecies);
                while ( $s=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db2)) {
                    echo "<option value='".$s['Species']."'>".$s['Species']."</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Angler's Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="angler" size="40"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Notes:</td><td><textarea rows="2" cols="40" name="notes"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Photo (optional):</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

Then the relevant part of addspecies.php is here:

```
$datecaught = $_POST['datecaught'];
$boatname = $_POST['boatname'] ;
$species = $_POST['species'];
$angler = $_POST['angler'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];

$bm = "SELECT BoatMake FROM SpeciesHuntBoats WHERE BoatName='$boatname'";
$q = mysql_query($bm);
$n = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$boatmake = $n['BoatMake'];

$skip = "SELECT Skipper FROM SpeciesHuntBoats WHERE BoatName='$boatname' AND CatchYear2='$year'";
$qq = mysql_query($skip);
$nn = mysql_fetch_assoc($qq);
$skipper = $nn['Skipper'];

$http_referrer = getenv( "HTTP_REFERER" );
// Image add
$imagename=$_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
//Get the content of the image and then add slashes to it 
$imagetmp=addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));

$query_rsCatch = "INSERT INTO SpeciesHunt (DateCaught, CatchYear, BoatName, BoatMake, Species, Species, Angler, Skipper, Notes, PhotoName, Photo) VALUES('$datecaught','$year','$boatname','$boatmake','$species','$species2','$angler','$skipper','$notes','$imagename','$imagetmp')";
$rsCatch = mysql_query($query_rsCatch, $webdb) or die(mysql_error());
```

How would I make it so a user can select, say 4 species and submit only once, but creating 4 separate entries in the database?

Comment: What have your tried? That should be pretty simple with a couple of loops.

Comment: You can create two tables one mater to store main information and species you can store into other tables based onyour selected array(multiple), iterate loop and store into table with reference of main table id. This is very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A multiple select should have an array style name:

```
<select name="species[]" multiple size="5">
```

Then in PHP, `$_POST['species']` will be an array containing all the selections. You can loop through the array and insert each of them.

```
foreach ($species as $s) {
    $query_rsCatch = "INSERT INTO SpeciesHunt 
        (DateCaught, CatchYear, BoatName, BoatMake, Species, Angler, Skipper, Notes, PhotoName, Photo) 
        VALUES('$datecaught','$year','$boatname','$boatmake','$s','$angler','$skipper','$notes','$imagename','$imagetmp')";
    $rsCatch = mysql_query($query_rsCatch, $webdb) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

You should also stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They were deprecated many years ago, and finally removed completely in PHP 7. Convert to PDO or mysqli, and also learn to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. This doesn't return any errors however it does only add one record to the database rather than all of the species selected

Comment: I left out the `mysql_query()` call. It needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you so much, I'm very grateful. Season's greetings.